# How is "jenkins pipeline steps" documentation of a plugin updated

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, influxdb

We are currently contributing to this Jenkins plugin which allows querying InfluxDB to fail a build based on queries:

- https://github.com/jenkinsci/influxdb-query-plugin

A version has been released and we updated Jenkins wiki:

- https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/InfluxDB+Query+Plugin

But this documentation is not editable and we guess generated from code analysis or plugin help page:

- https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/influxdb-query/

So could someone explain what needs to be done to have this documentation updated or point me to the documentation explaining it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the pipeline steps is updated via an automated job based on the released plugin.

Per answer provided by Daniel Beck:

- https://github.com/jenkins-infra/pipeline-steps-doc-generator/blob/c810a08f50f34d688eb69ec2ebab96947440f71d/Jenkinsfile#L5

The job runs  over the weekend.

reference : https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/jenkinsci-dev/Xo2kWiY2hoI/y-EU8x4QBQAJ